# Under the "this pc" I cant find my c:\, yet it still exists

Tags: windows, filesystems

Under the "this pc" I can't find my `c:\` yet it still exists. How can I make it show up under "this pc"?

It shows up here, and it says that it's in the "this pc":

[image: screenshot1]

When I go to "this pc" I can't find the `c:\` drive:

[image: screenshot2]

I have gone onto `regedit.msc` and computer management. And all the things say that it is not hiding, however it is and I can't find it.

This is my disk manager:

[image]

also in my computer in edit group policy editor, I am missing "windows explorer"

here is the scrolled up of my gpedit:

[image]

here is scrolled down (where it should be):

[image]

Comment: In your version of Windows, the correct folder is **File Explorer**. Look for the NoDrives key in this section.

Comment: how can I find this NoDrives key?

Comment: Click on the File Explorer folder. On the right you will see multiple Policies. Check for one with Drivers written on the label?

Comment: maybe check my second screenshot. I cant find a drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the C:\ drive!!!!!!

What I had to do was go to Regedit and go Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\
Explorer
In there I changed the NoDrives key value to 0 
Then restart my computer!

Thankyou to Natsu Kage for pointing me in the right direction. I will upvote u but it won't show up because my reputation is under 15.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoP5U.png)

Comment: Glad I could help. You might want to add which policy exactly you edited in this answer. (NoDrives ?)

Comment: ok i will do that

Answer (score 0):

Quoting Mr. Goo from [Microsoft Answers:](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/c-drive-is-not-visible-under-computer-or-windows/780067f0-787e-4d73-9947-ee926956d082)

> I have had the same issue. None of my users drives were showing up. It
>   came down to the registry key called NoDrives located at
>   HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer.
>
> When this key has a specific setting with will not show up in the open
>   menu or the Explorer navigation screen. You will be able to type c: in
>   the address bar and it will list the contents of the drive.
>
> Here is the TechNet website with the information on the registry
>   settings for this key.
>
> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938267.aspx

You need to check and change this policy if needed. To do this, go into the settings/control panel and find the Group Policy Editor. (Alternatively, you can type **gpedit.msc** from the start menu and press enter)
Next go to one of these here:

1. (User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\
   **Windows Explorer** )
2. (User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows
       Components\ **File Explorer** )
3. Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer

In this section you will find a policty named **NoDrives**. This policy needs to be set to **0** to be able to see all drives in the Explorer. Afterwards, Windows will need to be restarted for this policy to be effective.

Comment: @NatsuKage - You should edit your answer to reflect that fact.